# Recursive C function to compute sum of digits

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote a C program that computes the sum of digits of a number recursively. My question is if there is any other way, preferably faster, in which this procedure can be done.

This is my code, maybe I could have avoided the prototype function but I don't know if that will make it any faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int);

int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%d\n", &i);
    printf("%d", sum(i));
}

int sum(int x) {
    int res;
    if (x > 9) {
        res = (sum(x % 10) + sum(x / 10));
    } else {
        res = x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Getting rid of the recursion is the obvious improvement. All it achieves is to make the code slow and obscure. For nothing gained what-so-ever.

Comment: Why do you think the prototype makes it slower? It's just a help for the compilation step, it doesn't add any code in the compiled binary.

Comment: `sum(x%10)` → `x%10`

Comment: Even if you insisst on using recursion, you could reduce the number of recursive calls by replacing `sum(x % 10)` with just `x%10`. That will cause 1 call per digit instead of 2 calls per digit.

Comment: How fast is it now? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @konxanth, "maybe I could have avoided the prototype function but I don't know if that will make it any faster." --> Removing the prototype will not make code faster.

Comment: @konxanth, Given "compute sum of digits", do you expect `sum(-100)` to return 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it makes no sense to use recursion for this.  Here's a very simple iterative version which should be faster:

```
int sum(int x) {
    int res = 0;
    while (x) {
        res += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note that this assumes `x` is non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

- Recursion never leads to faster code. It very often leads to slower or buggier code which is harder to read. It also very often increases peak RAM consumption. All of it for absolutely nothing gained in return.
- The notable bottleneck here apart from recursion is division. Most CPUs perform division slowly.

Therefore the obvious way to improve this is to get rid of both of the above. If you know that the purpose is to sum the digits, you could instead take the input as a string.

```
int sum=0;
for(size_t i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
  sum += str[i] - '0';
```

Depending on CPU, this ought to be *many* times faster than what you have currently.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there is any other way, preferably faster, in which this procedure can be done.

Don't use recursion.

Recursion doesn't make code faster.  It makes certain algorithms easier to implement because you're not having to do your own bookkeeping.

Quicksort isn't fast because it's recursive; it's fast because it minimizes the number of comparisons and swaps by partitioning the list into partially sorted sublists.  It's often implemented recursively because it's easier than maintaining your own stack.

Conversely, a recursive Fibonacci implementation is extremely *slow* because you're computing the same terms multiple times (up to thousands of times for large N).

Lundin's and Tom's solutions are the better ways to go here.

Now, having said all that, no `int` is going to have more than 10 digits, so the deltas between the various algorithms will be almost immeasurable; it's only an issue if you're going to call this function *thousands* of times in your program.

> maybe I could have avoided the prototype function but I don't know if that will make it any faster.

The form of a declaration will have no effect on the runtime performance of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion does not help for this function and is quite inefficient in this case.

Here is a simpler version that can handle both positive and negative values:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int x) {
    int res = 0;
    while (x) {
        res += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return abs(res);
}
```

Comment: Nice full `int` range answer.

Comment: How should the negative numbers be handled.  should we consider all digits negative? or only the most significative one?  :)  IMHO this `sum()` routine should be better defined as `unsigned sum(unsigned x);`.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I do not think there is any ambiguity as to what the sum of the digits of `-123` should be: `6` just like that of `123`.  The above code does just that: `x % 10` is negative or zero for negative `x` and is exactly the negative value of the last digit. summing all these remainders gives the negated sum, finally `abs(res)` returns the positive sum for all numbers, positive, zero and negative ones, for the full range of type `int`.

Comment: Well, if you ad the digits with the sign of the number, then the result you will get is just the opposite (sum(-x) == -sum(x)) making it a hemisimetric function.  Depending on the problem, this can be the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct, *Some* C compilers *may* implement tail-call optimization and automatically convert tail-recursive code to iterative.

If we add an additional accumulator argument that accumulates the running sum to the function we can achieve tail recursion.

```c
int sum(int x, int acc) {
    if (x == 0) return acc;
    
    return sum(x / 10, acc + x % 10);
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    scanf("%d\n", &i);
    printf("%d", sum(i, 0));
}
```

We could hide this detail by defining a `sum_tailrec` function that takes the accumulator and then having `sum` call that function, initializing the accumulator to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you recursive function should be

```
unsigned sum(unsigned x)
{
    return x > 0
        ? sum(x / 10) + x % 10
        : 0;
}
```

as you know that the remainder of the division will be the digit itself, just add it to the sum of the number, without that last digit.  At some point the division will be 0, so the algorithm is warranted to finish.

Comment: one less division: `return x > 9 ? sum(x / 10) + x % 10 : x;`